# I am using my personal iPhone for development for the past 3 months, slowly my iPhone's performance is degrading

Tags: iphone

I am using my personal iPhone for development for the past 3 months, slowly my iPhone's performance is degrading.I dont charge my iPhone overnight even, i guess it's because of development usage connecting with xCode and building apps. Can you please help me to figure out the reason?

Comment: I have not experienced any correlation between using a phone for development and derogation in performance – can you elaborate you experience, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think its not because of Development if u think like that you can see in your mobile like
Settings > Battery

there you can see how much battery is consuming by Development Apps and other apps

https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-efficiently-test-your-mobile-app-for-battery 
this may use fun to